# How to reference the previous month's high or low in a data set and compare it with the current value

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet of daily Open/High/Low/Close data for an stock index (link below) and wish to go through the data day by day to create a marker for each day. I would like this to be +1 if the high of the day is above the high of the previous month, -1 if the low of the day is below the previous month's low and 0 if neither of these conditions are satisfied. A previous answer on this forum showed me how to extract the monthly high and low for each month (also in the spreadsheet). It seems quite straightforward on the face of it but I can't seem to get anywhere. I've been trying to use nested "if" statements to do this. I have actually asked this question before but I had no response. Any help would be much appreciated.
Many Thanks, Paul

Link to image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZmTv.jpg

Comment: Can you show some research? For example this previous answer you're talking about, why it isn't working, and what you are working with right now? This might help us determine where you have gone wrong. Also your image seems to be missing.

Comment: Apparently I am not allowed to add an image. I don't have enough reputations! Any ideas how to add my image?

Comment: I've added a link to the spreadsheet.

Comment: @pvwhite01 add the image to Imgur.com then paste the link back here, very few if any will download files from the internet.